# passed parameter of a stored procedure to insert?

Tags: sql

HI I want to take a passed parameters of a stored procedure, and then use that to update or add rows to a table. is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is.  Why do you ask?

Comment: I would like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example of how to do it.

```
-- Create the stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_TestSp
  @Param1 INT
AS
  INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (@Param1)
GO

-- Execute the stored procedure
EXEC dbo.usp_TestSp @Param1 = 2 -- int
```